# Select highest range of data

Tags: mysql

My table consists of a temperatures column which are filled into db every 10min, and i would like to find out when it was and what was the maximum daily range for temperatures for current month

this will select max daily temp

```
SELECT logDateTime, MAX(Temp)
FROM sibeniku_monthly
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(LogDateTime, "%m.") = 04
GROUP BY DAY(logDateTime)
```

and this min daily temp

```
SELECT logDateTime, MIN(Temp)
FROM sibeniku_monthly
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(LogDateTime, "%m.") = 04
GROUP BY DAY(logDateTime)
```

and now i need to tie them together.. like max value - min value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do so

```
SELECT logDateTime, MAX(Temp) `max`,
MIN(Temp) `min` ,
MAX(Temp) - MIN(Temp) `diff`
FROM sibeniku_monthly
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(LogDateTime, "%m.") = 04
GROUP BY DAY(logDateTime)
```

I above query it will do the calculation for min max twice to reduce it to one  do a subselect

```
SELECT t.* ,t.`max` - t.`min` `diff`
 FROM(
    SELECT logDateTime, MAX(Temp) `max`,
    MIN(Temp) `min` 
    FROM sibeniku_monthly
    WHERE DATE_FORMAT(LogDateTime, "%m.") = 04
    GROUP BY DAY(logDateTime)
) t
```

Comment: thank you sir! :) btw any idea how would i get what was the minimal difference between daily temperatures?

Comment: if want the smallest difference you can use `your query ORDER BY diff ASC LIMIT 1` and to find largest difference you can do so `your query ORDER BY diff DESC LIMIT 1`

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't

SELECT logDateTime, MAX(Temp), MIN(Temp)
FROM sibeniku_monthly
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(LogDateTime, "%m.") = 04
GROUP BY DAY(logDateTime)

do the trick?

Comment: i needed difference between those values :)